# Recover images from iPhone - creating image

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unix, data-recovery

I am following the steps from this site to recover deleted images from iPhone (I've tried other softwares, nothing has worked so far).

When I follow these steps, at the end I get the iphone.img file, the problem is that it has 0 bytes. Anybody has an idea of what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

The site is: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Recover_data_from_an_iPhone

Comment: sorry about that, I added it

Comment: What OS are you using to send the disk image to?